# BES10 Blackberry Device Service and Client Application Communication

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, mdm

I just started working on BES10 for Blackberry 10 devices, for Mobile Device Managerment(MDM) . I just gone through the documentation that are provided in the link `http://docs.blackberry.com/en/`.

Based on the given information, I understand that, I should have Blackberry Device Service configured in one machine and a client application.

Now my question is how does server notifies the client application to enable/disable particular settings, and what is API. If possible please provide a snippet of code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.  Are you coding for the BES of for an application on the BB10 device?

Comment: Actually, I am developing client application for MDM for BB10 devices. So, how the communication between BES and client application. Is it using Push notifications?

Comment: I don't think I can help here, since I am familiar with developing applications for BlackBerry devices rather than Servers.  But that said, I am still not clear on what you are actually asking for.  You seem to be developing something that runs on the Server and interacts with the BES 10 MDM management. This application would not interact directly with devices.  Is this what you are developing?  Can you point us at some sample APIs that you are using to develop this?  Or perhaps describe what you are trying to do?